# Why is the movie called “The Room”?

Tags: title, the-room

I saw this movie recently, it is drama genre. The character called Johnny whose future wife is not faithful and having a illicit relationship with Tommy, Johnny’s best friend.

Comment: Not to be confused with films "Room" (2005) or "Room" (2015).

Answer (score 13):

From [The New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/12/08/arts/tommy-wiseau-the-room.html):

> In an interview that was included as a DVD extra, Mr. Wiseau said the title had “a special meaning” to him.
>
> > At the time, I thought about a special place, a private place, a place where you can be safe. And it’s not a room, but it’s the room. I thought and I think that a lot of people would relate to it. So the room is a place where you can go, you can have a good time, you have a bad time, and a safe place.

Here is the DVD extra:

Comment: I must say, having just watched The Room the other day, I instantly recognized the voice of the interviewer as that of [Greg Sestero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greg_Sestero) (Mark from The Room).